# Introduce new name for C++ class and deprecate the old while keeping ABI compatibility during transition period

Tags: c++

I would like to introduce a new name for a C++ class in a library and offer a comfortable transition experience for the library user.

**Version 1.0:** Let's start with `class Old {};`.

**Version 1.1**: Introduce a new name like `using New = Old;` while keeping ABI compatibility with 1.0.

**Version 2.0**: Rename the `Old` class to `New` and provide a `using Old [[deprecated]] = New;` type alias, thereby breaking the ABI but keeping API compatibility.

**Version 2.1**: Remove the alias for `Old` thereby completing the transition.

My problem is: how to deprecate the library user's use of the name `Old` in version 1.1 to encourage them to switch to the new name `New`? If I simply go for `class [[deprecated]] Old {};` in version 1.1 then both the use of the name `Old` and `New` produce a compiler warning (in clang) since the alias is treated exactly like the symbol it is aliasing.

Comment: The way I read your question, at the end of the transition, `New` is **exactly** what `Old` used to be. Am I understanding it right or are you trying to make `New` an enhanced but backward-incompatible class to replace `Old`?

Comment: Is there a need for the second step at all? I'm struggling to see the value in it. If the main difference between "old" and "new" is ABI compatibility, you won't notice any of the problems that occur from that just by switching over the name, so now you break everyone's ABI "silently" in Version 2 anyway if they have switched to the new name but were still actually using the old class.

Comment: @Atmo I might want to introduce enhancements in version 2.0 that would also break the ABI even without the renaming but they would be API compatible with 1.1. But from 1.0 to 1.1, they are **exactly** the same. The idea is basically to spread the API change across versions 1.1, 2.0 and 2.1 so that the users gets a warning before the ABI change and a grace period after the ABI change.

Comment: @Atmo That is exactly my point: how to warn them in a way they can act upon that warning (by changing their code to use `New`) and thereby silencing the warning?

Comment: @axxel just introduce the "proper" `New` class in 1.1 already instead of making it an alias, deprecate `Old` right then and remove `Old` in 2.0. The problem you have is you're adding too many steps to the procedure

Comment: If you are on clang, have you tried deprecating `Old` in v1.1 and declaring `New` inside that construct (write the next 4 formatted piece on 4 lines)? `#pragma clang diagnostic push`
`#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"`
`using New = Old;`
`#pragma clang diagnostic pop`?

I expect there exist similar, although not identical, solutions for other compilers.

Comment: @Atmo I tried your `#pragma` suggestion now and it does not work, unfortunately.

Comment: Then I don't know.... BTW I concur with @Cubic. The role of the compiler is to warn if it detects anything that uses a deprecated class/function: client code, yes but also `New` and it is unclear on what criteria it should ignore it when your client compiles their files with a header from your API.

Comment: @Cubic I think I can see why my intention to warn already when using `Old` in version 1.1 is not really helping/changing much from a users perspective. It is sufficient to provide a deprecated alias `Old` in 2.0 to establish that transition period. Renaming already in 1.1 is not viable as it breaks semantic versioning. And 'adding' `New` is not viable ether, as I would have to duplicate all API consuming `Old` to now alternatively deal with `New`.